# Reading a text file into an array of objects using delimeters

Tags: java, arrays, file, object

Here are the contents of the file:
[Contents of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVTCd.png)

The first three lines of the file contain the teacher name, subject, and class period which are all stored in separate String variables.

The rest of the file contain the arguments for Student objects, the object has a signature of: Student(String name, int ID, int grade1, int grade2, int grade3, int grade5, int grade6, int grade7, int grade8, int grade9, int grade10)

I am trying to input the teacher name, subject, and class period and put each of them into separate String variables

Then input each student's info and create a new Student object and each Student object will then be put into a Student object array

Here is my code so far:

```
Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("Test.txt"));
Student array[] = new Student[3];
for(int x = 0; x < array.length; x++)
{
  String name = "";
  int id = 0, gradeOne = 0, gradeTwo = 0, gradeThree = 0, gradeFour = 0, gradeFive = 0, gradeSix = 0, gradeSeven = 0, gradeEight = 0, gradeNine = 0, gradeTen = 0;
  array[x] = new Student(name, id, gradeOne, gradeTwo, gradeThree, gradeFour, gradeFive, gradeSix, gradeSeven, gradeEight, gradeNine, gradeTen);

}
int counter = 0;
int index = 0;
sf.useDelimiter(",");

String teacher = "", subject = "", period = "";

while(sf.hasNext())
{
  if(counter == 0)
  {
    teacher = sf.nextLine();

    counter++;
  }

  else if(counter == 1)
  {
    subject = sf.nextLine();
    counter++;
  }

  else if(counter == 2)
  {
    period = sf.nextLine();
    counter++;
  }

  else
  {
    array[index].studentName = sf.next();
    array[index].studentID = sf.nextInt();
    array[index].grade1 = sf.nextInt();
    array[index].grade2 = sf.nextInt();
    array[index].grade3 = sf.nextInt();
    array[index].grade4 = sf.nextInt();
    array[index].grade5 = sf.nextInt();
    array[index].grade6 = sf.nextInt();
    array[index].grade7 = sf.nextInt();
    array[index].grade8 = sf.nextInt();
    array[index].grade9 = sf.nextInt();
    array[index].grade10 = sf.nextInt();
    index++;
  }

}


for(int g = 0; g < index; g++)
{
  System.out.println(array[g].studentName + "\t" + array[g].studentID + "\t" + array[g].grade1 + "\t" + array[g].grade2 + "\t" + array[g].grade3 + "\t" + array[g].grade4 + "\t" + array[g].grade5 + "\t" + array[g].grade6 + "\t" + array[g].grade7 + "\t" + array[g].grade8 + "\t" + array[g].grade9+ "\t" + array[g].grade10);
  }
```

When I run the program I am given a InputMismatchException, does this mean that the first three lines of the file also require a comma? Or am I doing something else wrong? And is this the best way to input the file any suggestions would help, thank you.

Comment: A) provide a real [mcve] (like a complete stack trace with line numbers, and telling us which lines in your source code is pointed out) B) "any suggestions" is in general not what this site is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `nextInt()` with the delimiter as `,` will read the integer from comma to comma. So, after grade10 is read at the end of the line, there is no comma! So the scanner reads up to the next line's name therefore causing an `InputMismatchException`.

If you added the comma to the end of the grade10 in the text file, that solves half the problem.

e.g. `Jones Alex,532675,100,100,55,85,88,89,100,55,32,66,`

The next problem is that the scanner does not point to the next line  but rather stays on the same line where the comma previously was (i.e. right after the 66.).

I recommend calling `sf.nextLine()` without storing its value at the end of each while iteration just before the `index++;` in your code.